# Открытие модального окна по таймеру за одну сессию

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!

```js
    // Проверяем, было ли модальное окно уже показано в текущей сессии
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('modalShown=true') === -1) {
        // Если нет, то устанавливаем куку с флагом показа и открываем модальное окно через 25 секунд
        setTimeout(function () {
            openModal();
            document.cookie = 'modalShown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/';
        }, 25000); // 25000 миллисекунд = 25 секунд
    }

    // Функция для открытия модального окна
    function openModal() {
        var modal = document.getElementById('OpenNew');
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    }

    // Функция для закрытия модального окна
    function closeModal() {
        var modal = document.getElementById('OpenNew');
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
    <div id="OpenNew" class="modal_contact_ind">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="modal-content_php_2">

                    <?php require_once('contactopen.php'); ?>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, модальное окно должно открываться через 25 секунд после запуска страницы и при закрытии запоминать что оно было открыто в данной сессии.
Но почему-то не работает :(
Может у кого-то есть готовое решение

Comment: Что именно не срабатывает?